# Comparing elements in a numpy array, finding pairs, how to deal with edges/corners

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a function below, but I'm not how to exactly to execute this.

Let's say I have a 2D numpy array like

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4], [ 1,  6,  7,  8], [ 1,  1,  1, 12], [13,  3, 15, 16]])
```

This is a 4x4 matrix, which looks like this when printed:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  1,  1, 12],
       [13,  3, 15, 16]])
```

I want to access the elements of `arr` and compare them to each other. For each element, I would like to see whether all surrounding eight elements (top, bottom, left, right, top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right) are greater than, less than, or equal to this element I'm at.

I thought about using a if statement in a function like this:

```
if arr[i][j] == arr[i][j+1]:
    print("Found a pair! %d is equal to %d, it's in location (%d, %d)", % (arr[i][j], arr[i][j+1], i, j+1))
elif: 
    arr[i][j] > arr[i][j+1]:
        print("%d is greater than %d, it's in location (%d, %d)", % (arr[i][j], arr[i][j+1], i, j+1))
else:
    print("%d is less than %d, it's in location (%d, %d)", % (arr[i][j], arr[i][j+1], i, j+1))
```

However, (1) I have to do this for all eight surrounding element positions and (2) I'm not sure how to write the function such that it moves from position to position correctly. Somehow one must use recursion for this to work, I think. One could possibly use a while loop as well.

I'm planning on saving all the "pairs" with are equal, and creating a dictionary with these.

EDIT1:

There is still a problem I'm having to understand where the dimensions are:

Our original matrix is shaped (4,4):

When we compare for adjacent pairs horizontally, we find an array shaped (4,3):

```
arr[:-1] == arr[1:]

#output 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

When we compare for adjacent pairs vertically, we find an array shaped (3,4):

```
arr[:, :-1] == arr[:, 1:]
# output
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

When I combine these two to see whether there are pairs *both* vertically and horizontally, how do I know I am not mixing up positions?

Comment: Do you want to include the edges and corners?

Comment: @Evert Yes. For the corner above at (0,0) the element "1" should be compared to "2", "6" and "1". 
For the edge point "8", there only five points to compare. 
This is what makes me nervous about my scheme above. I would have to write in exceptions.

Comment: And do you want the indices of the two matching elements, or just their value. (In the latter case, for the value of `1`, you would have no idea which matches are included, obviously.)

Comment: Both indices and values. But, let's take this one step at a time...

Comment: Well, if you have the indices, you have the values automatically.

Comment: Interesting bit I just noticed: your printed array is *not* the same as your input array. Please fix whatever is appropriate, and next time, please copy-paste properly.

Comment: @Evert Apologies. Corrected.

Comment: I've used a modification of your old input array as example in my answer. My example array has a matching `3` extra, and a lot more `1` matches (e.g., the `1` at position `(1, 1)` has 3 matches, and so does the `1` at `(1, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't find it entirely clear what you want to do, adjacent array slices might be a convenient method. For example, `arr[:-1] == arr[1:]` will tell you where there are pairs in adjacent rows. Then, `arr[arr[:-1] == arr[1:]]` can give you an array of those values and `argwhere` can give you the indexes.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr
array([[3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2]])

>>> hpairs = (arr[:, :-1] == arr[:, 1:])
>>> hpairs
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> arr[hpairs]
array([3, 2, 3, 1, 3])

>>> np.argwhere(hpairs)
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Change the `==` operator and directions of slices as needed.

That we get a smaller array as a result of the comparison makes sense. After all, the number of possible horizontal pairs is one less than the array width. If either slice used for the comparison `arr[:, :-1] == arr[:, 1:]` is indexed with the boolean array, we get the left or the right numbers of the pairs. Analogously for the other directions.

What if there are pairs in multiple directions? That depends on what you want to do with them, I suppose. Let's say you want to find clusters of at least three equal numbers in the shape of an L turned 180 degrees. In other words, any position that is the upper of a vertical, and the right of a horizontal pair. (Same sample data as before.)

```
>>> vpairs = (arr[:-1] == arr[1:])
>>> hpairs[:-1] & vpairs[:, 1:]
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

If you want to count the number of equal neighbors at each position, here is one way to do it.

```
>>> backslashpairs = (arr[:-1, :-1] == arr[1:, 1:])
>>> slashpairs = (arr[1:, :-1] == arr[:-1, 1:])
>>> 
>>> equal_neighbors = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=int)
>>> equal_neighbors[:-1] += vpairs
>>> equal_neighbors[1:] += vpairs
>>> equal_neighbors[:, :-1] += hpairs
>>> equal_neighbors[:, 1:] += hpairs
>>> equal_neighbors[1:, :-1] += slashpairs
>>> equal_neighbors[:-1, 1:] += slashpairs
>>> equal_neighbors[:-1, :-1] += backslashpairs
>>> equal_neighbors[1:, 1:] += backslashpairs
>>> equal_neighbors
array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0]])
```

Comment: This is great! And I don't have to loop through numpy arrays! Thanks, I was having a mental block. 
Using indexing, how could I compare diagonals? I think if we iterate through the top and bottom rows based on the current row, that would work.

Comment: For diagonals: `arr[:-1, :-1] == arr[1:, 1:]` and `arr[:-1, 1:] == arr[1:, :-1]`

Comment: Here is a dimension problem I'm facing: the original matrix has a certain dimension. When you compare for adjacent rows, this Boolean matrix has a different dimension in contract to comparing adjacent columns. Ditto with diagonals. How could we simultaneously check for all pairs?

Comment: I made an edit above to explain what I mean. The ending result should be (3,3), but am I mixing up entries?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was thinking about somehow creating a "template" matrix and using this. However, there's no standard dimension, and you skip pairs somehow.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some nice numpy or scipy function out there that does this, but not one I know of.

Below is one solution to solve this.

To add some confusion to it, I have indexed the *rows* with `x`, and the *columns* with `y`. That simply means that the element at `(2, 1)` is `7`.

The trick with edges and corners is simply to expand the matrix with a border, that is later ignored.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 12], [13, 3, 15, 16]])
arr2 = np.zeros((arr.shape[0]+2, arr.shape[1]+2), dtype=arr.dtype)
arr2[1:-1,1:-1] = arr
results = np.zeros(arr2.shape + (9,), dtype=np.int)
print(arr)

transform = {'y': [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1],
             'x': [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]}
for x in range(1, arr2.shape[0]-1):
    for y in range(1, arr2.shape[1]-1):
        subarr = arr2[x-1:x+2,y-1:y+2].flatten()
        mid = len(subarr)//2
        value = subarr[mid]
        greater = (subarr > value).astype(np.int)
        smaller = (subarr < value).astype(np.int)
        results[x,y,:] += greater
        results[x,y,:] -= smaller

results = np.dstack((results[1:-1,1:-1,:4], results[1:-1,1:-1,5:]))
xpos, ypos, zpos = np.where(results == 0)
matches = []
for x, y, z in zip(xpos, ypos, zpos):
    matches.append(((x, y), x+transform['x'][z], y+transform['y'][z]))
print(matches)
```

which results in

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 1  1  7  8]
 [ 1  2  3 12]
 [13  3 15 16]]
[((0, 0), 1, 0), ((0, 0), 1, 1), ((1, 0), 0, 0), ((1, 0), 1, 1), ((1, 0), 2, 0), ((1, 1), 0, 0), ((1, 1), 1, 0), ((1, 1), 2, 0), ((2, 0), 1, 0), ((2, 0), 1, 1), ((2, 2), 3, 1), ((3, 1), 2, 2)]
```

In the above code, I store neighbouring matches for equal, greater or larger than as 0, 1 or -1 in a z-dimension. By using a simple transformation, the index of the z-dimension translates to an offset from the point under consideration.

The `dstack` step is not really necessary, but it gets rid of both the added border, and the self-matches (there's no simply way to "slice out" an element in the middle of an array).

Pairs for greater or smaller than matches can be found by simply chaning the where condition, since those matches are stored as 1 or -1 in the `results` array.

I am not using a dict to store the result, since this is essentially not possible: a single point can have multiple matches: a dict could only store one match for a single point (using a (x, y) coordinate tuple as key). Hence the matches are stored in a list, with each element a tuple of

```
((x, y), (xmatch, ymatch))
```

tuples

Since each pair is matched both ways, all matching pairs are contained twice in `matches`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Adjacent array splices is more computationally efficient in numpy though